# Is it possible to show Smiley/Emoticon/Image span in android notification text?

Tags: android, notifications, emoticons

I'm trying to show smiley(or a image span) in android notification text. And its not working. Anyone know how to do it ? Thanks.

Code is below:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
builder.setSpan(imageSpan,0, 1,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Imagespan works everywhere, but not in notification.

Solved,
Thanks,Imagespan won't work.But i solved the problem using unicode.

Comment: i added image span to text.In Notification image span is not working. its showing the text on which i spanned the image.

Comment: Thanks,i solved the problem by using unicodes. Imagespan won't work.

Comment: Can you tell us, how did you use the Unicode in this case ?

Comment: Dear @vakman,
Can you advice me how did you solve it using unicodes ?

Comment: int unicode =0x1F604; `new String(Character.toChars(unicode))` will give you unicoded string.

Comment: I got your idea, but in my case I have a string containing emojis(as SB unicode, ex :\ue415), so how can I convert that string to a set of unicode characters in order to pass it to the notification?

Comment: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); sb.append("\ue415");` That unicode will be shown if android has or if available in font family.

Comment: Also,you can use custom notification.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958429/android-wear-notification-image-span-is-not-working/32139242#32139242

Answer (score 1):

At server side,
Encode your message using URLEncoder.encode() method.

In your android app,
Decode the same message using URLDecoder.decode() method.