# Android wear - Notification - Image Span is not working

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, wear-os

I am using ImageSpan in Android wear notification for styling in notification, but it's not working. Please tell me the procedure how to use ImageSpan in notifications any help is Appreciated. Following sample code i'm using.

SpannableStringBuilder title = new SpannableStringBuilder();

title.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, bmp, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE),title.length()+2,title.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, imagespan can not work in notification currently, and i get the official response is that the google design it is.

Answer (score 6):

You can not use ImageSpan in Notification.

---

If you want to show images, there are two approaches to do it.
 **1. Custom Notification**
   This is a code snip

```
      RemoteViews contentViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.view_notice_common);
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        contentViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notice_time, fmt.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
        contentViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notice_title, title);
        contentViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notice_extend_message, content);
        Bitmap smallBitmap = bundle.getParcelable("APP_ICON");
        if (smallBitmap != null) {
            contentViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.notice_drawable, smallBitmap);
        } else {
            contentViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.notice_drawable, R.drawable.icon);
        }
        notification.contentView = contentViews;
```

[image]

**2. Use Unicode Data**
   Code snip

```
  String originalStr = "emoji-" + newString(0x1f602) +newString(0x1f684)+"--over";
  public static final String newString(int codePoint) {
     return new String(Character.toChars(codePoint));
}
```

Then use originalStr as the Title Text.
 [image]